# Unpack dictionary without knowledge of its key name

Tags: python, dictionary, unpack

If I have some dictionary like:

```
d = {'keyname': ['foo', 'bar']}
```

and I don't know the key name how I would unpack this dict in two variables?

This doesn't work:

```
k,v = d
```

I could iterate over this dict like:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    # k and v are now available
```

But I think this is not the "pythonic" way enough

How can I do this without using a for-loop?

`"d"` can always have only ONE `key:val` pair.

Comment: Must work with Python 3!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use iterable unpacking:

```
>>> d = {'keyname': ['foo', 'bar']}
>>> [(k, v)] = d.items()
>>> k
'keyname'
>>> v
['foo', 'bar']
>>>
```

This works in both Python 2.x and Python 3.x.

Note however that if you are using Python 2.x, it would be slightly more efficient to use `d.iteritems()` instead of `d.items()`:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> d = {'keyname': ['foo', 'bar']}
>>> timeit('[(k, v)] = d.items()', 'from __main__ import d')
0.786108849029695
>>> timeit('[(k, v)] = d.iteritems()', 'from __main__ import d')
0.6730112346680928
>>>
```

This is because `iteritems` returns an iterator while `items` builds an unnecessary list.

Answer (score 2):

In Python **2.x**
If your `dictionary` is always going to be of length 1 then this can be one possible solution:

```
>>> d = {'keyname': ['foo', 'bar']}
>>> k, v = d.keys()[0], d.values()[0]
>>> k
'keyname'
>>> v
['foo', 'bar']
```

For both Python **2.x** and **3.x**
Using `.items()`

```
>>> k, v = d.items()[0]
>>> k
'keyname'
>>> v
['foo', 'bar']
```

For python **3.x**

```
>>> d = {'keyname': ['foo', 'bar']}
>>> k, v = tuple(d.keys())[0], tuple(d.values())[0]
>>> k
'keyname'
>>> v
['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: This doesn't work with Python 3! I should mention it, it must work under Python 3

Comment: @user2624744 Thanks for reminding about `.keys()` and `.values()` updation in python 3.

Answer (score 0):

d = {'keyname': ['foo', 'bar']}

for k in d.keys():
    key = k

```
val = d[k]

print key, val
```